# Joining 2 sql table into one table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Im trying to link a list of ID to a list of date in SQL.

This is the data i have both in different table.

```
|   Date   | ID |
|2017-12-25| 1  |
|2017-12-26| 2  |
|2017-12-27| 3  |
```

I will like to merge this into

```
|   Date   | ID |
|2017-12-25| 1  |
|2017-12-25| 2  |
|2017-12-25| 3  |
|2017-12-26| 1  |
|2017-12-26| 2  |
|2017-12-26| 3  |
|2017-12-27| 1  |
|2017-12-27| 2  |
|2017-12-27| 3  |
```

Comment: Edit your answer and insert what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `CROSS JOIN` for SQL Server

```
select a.[date], t.id from table t
cross join 
(
    select * from table
)a
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to `MERGE`

```
MERGE table1 <alias1>
USING table2 <alias2>
ON <alias1>.ID = <alias2>.ID
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT (ID, Date)
VALUES (<alias1>.ID, <alias1>.Date);

SELECT * FROM table1;
```